# How can I host a WCF REST service at the service root address (without trailing slash)?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, wshttpbinding

I have a service hosted using wsHttpBinding on an address (the host base address is http://localhost/MyService).

In my contract (`IMyService`), I have:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "/")]
    Stream GetRootPage();
```

If I run my service and browse to http://localhost/MyService/, it works fine.  If I browse to http://localhost/MyService, I am greeted with a default WCF page indicating that the metadata publishing service is not enabled for this service.

I have tried various combinations of UriTemplate:

- UriTemplate = ""
- UriTemplate = "/"
- UriTemplate = "*"

In combination with the service base address:

- http://localhost/MyService
- http://localhost/MyService/

All of them yield the same behavior.  At some point previously, I could have sworn this was working, though I think I may have been using a subpath in the UriTemplate.  I know that if I have a UriTemplate of "/abc/123/", I can browse to /abc/123 (without the trailing slash) because WCF actually issues an HTTP 307 redirect automatically.

I am using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

Ensure that the default WSDL generation is disabled (or at least not using the default URL):

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
```

Ensure that the help URL is disabled:

```
<serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is already answered in: [Simple URL routes in WCF Rest 4.0 without trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970951/simple-url-routes-in-wcf-rest-4-0-without-trailing-slash).

Can you verify that?

Comment: I saw that before, though looking at it more closely, I did not see the ServiceRoute code.  My initial assumption was that the service hosted there was www.domain.com, and the UriTemplate used was "cars."  Let me play around with my code a bit more.

Comment: Looking at this more, it does not answer my question.  This is adding a route so that multiple services are essentially hosted at the same address.  I am essentially just trying to host something on the root address (without the trailing slash)