# ServiceRoute overriding Existing routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

a newbee in MVC patterns, so please bear it with me.

i have defined a `ServiceRoute` in `global.asax` file

```
  RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("rest", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ServiceName)));
```

this route is now overriding my existing routes. to better explain this,  its setting as `"/rest/Controller/Action"`. but this has to be `"/Controller/Action"`

`RouteEngine` is appending my `ServiceRoute` in Actions `calls`.

how can i set the exact mapping  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use constraints, and register routes in the right order.

You can get a [full explanation of what's happening here](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2011/05/09/using-serviceroute-with-existing-mvc-routes/).

When reading it remember that the MapServiceRoute method has dissapeared, and the way to register services is what you have chosen.

You don't need to implement IRouteCOnstraint. You can just use a regex.

Comment: Thanks for your input, if i dont have to use `IRouteConstaint`. then i should write like  `routes.IgnoreRoute("{rest}");`. please Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No! Every route map defines "who" handles the matching url. The routing system tries to match the url in the map registration order. The first matching route decides "who" handles it, and no more routes are checked. IgnoreRoute is an special map which means that "noone" will handle that url, so that url is discarded an no more routes are checked. This is used i.e. for .axd, .asmx, or any other special http handlers in the web site. In this case is interesting to discard the url, so it's handled by something external to the route table. You can use directly a "regex" instead of IRouteConstraint

Comment: i tried this `routes.IgnoreRoute("(rest).*$");` but still routing System intercepting this

Comment: No, you can't do that using the IgnoreRoute!! And IgnoreRoute doesn't support Regex. Look here to see how to use the constraint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570887/mvc2-routing-with-wcf-serviceroute-html-actionlink-rendering-incorrect-links

Comment: you know you just saved my hairs.